# What's the best/cheapest geocoding service for converting 100,000+ entries at once?

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, arcgis

I have 100,000+ addresses that need to be geocoded, but most geocoding services seem to cost money after the first couple thousand entries. Is there any free service that can geocode what I need either in one go or in a relatively short amount of time i.e. a couple weeks at most while being free or relatively cheap?

Also, I may have access to arcgis and I'm wondering if arcgis's geocoding service have a limit if you have the premium version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No, there are no free services that will handle 100,000+ entries.

Although it can be argued that one can write a script that will handle geocoding actions in sequence and parallel, i.e. Google's geocoding API with 100 instances running at 2500/day. It is unrealistic and violates their [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).

To my knowledge, ArcGIS also has a limit as well.

Your best bet is that if this is company or business related, have them foot the bill.